# codeigniter sessions gets unset after redirect when opening in iframe

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, iframe

I have one website in codeigniter thats run perfect. but, when I try it in `iframe` tag and I login, it's store session but when redirects its unset the session and keep showing the login screen.

it only happens when I run this in localhost, On same server its working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="https://www.mywebsite.com" width="900" height="600"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

please help me with this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: What versions of PHP are you running on both servers?

Comment: @SH_ on live server 7.3.17 and on local 7.1.16. But I dont think that can cause the issue.

Comment: @jaypatel any update on this, i have the same issue, but php 5.4 with codeigniter 2,
iframe is in php 7+.